# Shall we add a [milestones] tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I've asked a question about milestones payments, and I wonder whether using milestones is such a common project management or payment approach that a tag to signify it would be helpful.

Based on [this search](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/search?q=milestone+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano), there are presently nine questions that presently could have this tag added (they'd have to be manually checked of course).

Does anyone else think this would be a useful tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding tags, I always ask myself, "Is there an expert in **topic** who would benefit by looking for questions like this?". If so, I'll add the tag to my question.

I could see a few good questions around that topic, but I don't know about any "experts" in that field, so I'm inclined to say no. I do not speak for the community as a whole though, and we would like to not have to go through a bunch of old questions to simply add a tag. We want the edits to be substantial, and useful edits.

I simply ask you to take that into consideration. I don't feel it would benefit the site enough to edit the old questions, but you can certainly make one for future questions. Just don't become a tag-*<insert random word here>* just because you have the ability to.

Comment: Thanks Luke. My view from Stack Overflow is that excessively general words are not worth making tags for, and they are often removed as lacking specificity. However, I tend to see noun tags as adding search engine value (the primary tag is added automatically to page titles) and perhaps for emphasising what the OP sees as the critical theme of their question. I wanted to add it [to this question](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/3505/8370). Nevertheless, I am not strongly invested in getting this tag created, so if no-one is willing to support it, that's OK.

Comment: In that particular case, [tag:payment-terms] should cover it (essentially, what a mile stone is, in the end... Right?)

Comment: That's one usage of the term, but milestones are also a project management device unrelated to payments.

Comment: @halfer if it can be its own topic, make the tag. Like I said, this is my opinion, I just want a couple of points to be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: I hear you, and I appreciate your input. I don't think I have the reputation to create a tag, and in any case I agree it should only be created if it can get support from other community members. I'm happy to wait to see if any other answers come in.